# Multiple OnClickListener with case

Tags: android, android-studio, switch-statement, case, onclicklistener

Here is the sample i'm doing:

[image]

Hi i want to ask if it's possible to set the calculator buttons on a single `OnClickListener` with a Case switch statement, it would be helpful if there's an answer

Comment: Show what have you tried?

Comment: its possible, you can add tags to your views and in on click listener  get tag and determine what you have clicked.

Comment: actually i tried using case statement but i can't seem to implement it in my main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. do the following things :

1. implement onclickListener in your activity and override onClick method
2. In onCreate add listeners for all the buttons like

   ```
    btn1.setonclickListner(this);
    btn2.setonclickListner(this);
   ```

   and so on

   3. In onCLick() method use switch case to check id values of buttons as :

      switch(v.getId())
      and make cases with your button ids like R.id.btn1 , R.id.btn2 etc

Comment: thank you for the answer but i was hoping that i won't need that many setonclickListner, or is it really impossible to assign a conditional setonclickListner

Comment: its impossible to use a single onclickListener for all the buttons, you will at least need to set listeners for all of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View.setonclickListner(this);//must add to each view for onclicklistener to work
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id =view.getId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.View : 
            //your code here
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't quite get it, i tried your code but it doesn't seem to change the textview when i used setText()

Comment: case R.id.btn1 :
                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvsum);
                textView.setText("123");
                break;